# Subtracting hours from datetime format

Tags: xslt

I have a date-time field which returns the value as: 2013-02-01T10:00:00Z
I want to substract 4hrs from the time (I want the time as GMT-4)
So the output should be 2013-02-01T06:00:00Z

Can somebody help me how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Nitika

Comment: are you working with XSLT 2.0? it seems that is easier than in 1.0: https://www.google.ch/#hl=de&biw=1518&bih=883&sclient=psy-ab&q=xslt+subtract+day+from+date&oq=xslt+subtract+&gs_l=hp.3.2.0i19l3j0i30i19.338.12129.0.13781.32.19.7.5.8.0.401.2714.8j7j2j1j1.19.0...1.0...1c.1.4.psy-ab.pOrMNvMLLmM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42965579,d.Yms&fp=76de7bbb07fa601c

Comment: I tried: <hed:MessageSentDateTime> <xsl:value-of select="xs:subtract-dayTimeDuration-from-dateTime(/cancellation:Envelope/cancellation:Header/hed:MessageSentDateTime,4)"/> </hed:MessageSentDateTime> but it doesnot work

Comment: I am using xslt 2.0 but i want to substract 4 hours from the datetime format(2013-02-01T10:00:00Z )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For achieving what you are trying to do in XSLT 2.0 you could specify an xs:dayTimeDuration('PT4H') and subtract it to the dateTime that you have.

So, if you have the following XML file:

```
<datetime value="2013-02-01T10:00:00Z" />
```

And you apply the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="datetime">
        <xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime(@value) - xs:dayTimeDuration('PT4H')" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You obtain the following result:

```
2013-02-01T06:00:00Z
```

Comment: Thanks once again Pablo..you always provide accurate solution and solve my problem..:) I hope i can get trained by you in xslt :)

Comment: If you are interested this is the book that I used to learn XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0. http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527211.do

Comment: Can we do  the same way with XSLT 1.0?